# Will you find more weapons suited to your character?

Tags: dead-island

Right now my character is the sharp-bladed weapon expert, and I'm halfway through Act 2 and I have not found a single firearm (but many knives, etc).  If I choose the firearms expert, will I be able to find a guns or is it still too early in the game?

Are drops tailored to the character's strengths?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as your first question (will I find guns as the firearms expert), I'm also in the middle of Act II as the firearms expert (Purna), and can say that previous to adventuring into the city I'd only ever found two guns (a fairly bad pistol as a quest reward in Act I, and a single-shot rifle from a chest in Act II).  However, the city seems to have numerous locations with respawning non-zombie baddies carrying a variety of medicore pistols, and tons of ammo.  Additionally, Purna's fury allows her to draw a firearm and fire six shots, regardless of whether or not you actually have ammo (and it won't consume any of your ammo).  Additionally, in Act III, numerous enemies will wield both rifles and pistols.

As for your second question (are drops tailored), it seems the general consensus is that they are not.  Acts II and III are filled to the brim with firearms, and you can get ammo mod recipes for all three types of guns (pistols, shotguns, and rifles).

Comment: I recently completed the game and must say that all humans dropped the same items. It's a possibility, though, that zombies have a better chance of dropping items for the specific class, but I doubt it. I usually focused on buying greens, purples, blues. and oranges from shop and had no issue with money. Unfortunately, after 5 levels or so, white weapons are just as good as your normal weapons...

Answer (score 2):

Drops are not tailored. There's just not many guns before act II, and even in act II, only punks drop guns/ammo, and they're only located in certain parts of the city. I'm not sure if they become more common later on, but I assume not, guns/ammo are supposed to be rare/precious.

Answer (score 0):

I am at about lvl 35+ guns expert still in act2, virtually all punks drop 15-shot automatic pistols.

Aside from those, I have found 3 revolvers (worthless IMO), one shotgun with maybe 15 rounds, one full-auto assault with 20 rounds, and two semi-auto assault rifles, each with 20 rounds. The punks occasionally drop pistol ammo, but I have not come across ANY shotgun or rifle ammo. I found a pistol ammo recipe, but no ammo recipes yet.

The shotgun I found was useless. The jury is out on the assault rifles because I have no ammo. The pistols are OK with a shock mod, but they take time, and ammo carry capacity is pretty low, even with the 3 ammo carry boost perks.

Answer (score 0):

Well the guns and the throw expert(s) are not tailored to each character, but heavy and sharp have their weapons found with a small increase.

Comment: Do you think you could elaborate on this a bit? It does not provide anything new to the question or its answers...

Comment: @ColeBusby actually it seems to be the only answer to say that drops depend on the character you're playing.

Comment: @kotekzot edit the answer to show that outright and I'll change my vote and comment, otherwise I don't see that.